# Create array of object from 3 arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 3 private methods in the angular component which return arrays of objects.

I need to create one array of the object which will contain all 3. All of them has the same class

Here is it

```
 export class TimelineItemDto {
    id: any;
    creatorAvatarUrl: string;
    categoryName: string;
    creatorName: string;
    subcategoryName: string;
    description: string;
    type: string;
}
```

Here is the code of the component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  color: ThemePalette = 'primary';
  classes: TimelineItemDto[] = [];
  requests: TimelineItemDto[] = [];
  courses: TimelineItemDto[] = [];
  timelineItems: TimelineItemDto[] = [];
  checked = false;
  disabled = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    if (!token) {
      this._router.navigate(['/main/login']);
    }

    this.getTimelineItems();
  }

  getCourses(): any {
    return this.http
      .get(environment.baseUrl + '/Course/GetCourses')
      .subscribe((data: TimelineItemDto[]) => {
        return data;
      });
  }
  getClasses(): any {
    return this.http
      .get(environment.baseUrl + '/Class/GetClasses')
      .subscribe((data: TimelineItemDto[]) => {
        return data;
      });
  }
  getRequest(): any {
    return this.http
      .get(environment.baseUrl + '/Requests/GetRequests')
      .subscribe((data: TimelineItemDto[]) => {
        return data;
      });
  }

  getTimelineItems(): any {
    var courses = this.getCourses();
    var classes = this.getClasses();
    var requests = this.getRequest();
    this.timelineItems = [...classes, ...courses, ...requests];
    console.log(this.timelineItems);
  }
}
```

At this row `this.timelineItems = [...classes, ...courses, ...requests];` I have this error

> core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: classes is not iterable

How I can fix this?

Comment: You have also async problem. You will probably combine empty arrays. Because in async functions doesnt wait anothers.

Comment: I have 3 arrays of objects, I need to make 1 of it, so I'm not looking for an object creation @NicholasK

Comment: How I can fix this? @pc_coder

Comment: `getClasses()` is returning an observable and not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how asynchronous data works. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921) for more info on async data.

In short, you need to wait till the data is emitted by the source. In this specific case, you need to wait for the RxJS observables emit the values before trying to assign them. And seeing that you need to subscribe to multiple observables, you could use RxJS `forkJoin` function to trigger the requests in parallel

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  color: ThemePalette = 'primary';
  classes: TimelineItemDto[] = [];
  requests: TimelineItemDto[] = [];
  courses: TimelineItemDto[] = [];
  timelineItems: TimelineItemDto[] = [];

  checked = false;
  disabled = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    if (!token) {
      this._router.navigate(['/main/login']);
    }

    this.getTimelineItems();
  }

  getTimelineItems(): any {
    forkJoin(
      <Observable<TimelineItemDto[]>>this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + '/Class/GetClasses'),
      <Observable<TimelineItemDto[]>>this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + '/Course/GetCourses'),
      <Observable<TimelineItemDto[]>>this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + '/Requests/GetRequests')
    ).subscribe({
      next: ([classes, courses, requests]) => {
        this.classes = classes;
        this.courses = courses;
        this.requests = requests;
        this.timelineItems = [...classes, ...courses, ...requests];
        console.log(this.timelineItems);
      },
      error: error => {
        console.log('handle error');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Please go through the link above. The variable `this.timelineItems` might still be empty when you try to access it outside the subscription as it might not yet be assigned the values.

In other words, the `this.timelineItems` would only be properly accessible inside the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem

Consider the code below

```typescript
  getCourses(): any {
    return this.http
      .get(environment.baseUrl + '/Course/GetCourses')
      .subscribe((data: TimelineItemDto[]) => {
        return data;
      });
  }
```

The above code calls `.get()` method then calls `.subscription()` method. This indicates that this method actually returns a subscription and **NOT** an `Observable`. As the error indicates you are trying to iterate over these subscription hence the error

### Solution

To solve this, there are various ways, my approach will be as below

- get classes as `Observable`
- get requests as `Observable`
- get courses as `Observable`
- combine these 3 `Observables` to one `Observable`
- subscribe to the new `Observable`

See Below code

```typescript
  constructor(private _router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {}
  color: ThemePalette = "primary";
  timelineItems: TimelineItemDto[] = []
  getCourses = () =>
    this.http.get<TimelineItemDto[]>(
      environment.baseUrl + "/Course/GetCourses"
    );

  getClasses = () =>
    this.http.get<TimelineItemDto[]>(environment.baseUrl + "/Class/GetClasses");

  getRequest = () =>
    this.http.get<TimelineItemDto[]>(
      environment.baseUrl + "/Requests/GetRequests"
    );

  classes$: Observable<TimelineItemDto[]> = this.getClasses();
  requests$: Observable<TimelineItemDto[]> = this.getRequest();
  courses$: Observable<TimelineItemDto[]> = this.getCourses();
  timelineItems$: Observable<TimelineItemDto[]> = combineLatest([
    this.classes$,
    this.courses$,
    this.requests$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([classes, courses, requests]) => [...classes, ...courses, ...requests])
  );
  checked = false;
  disabled = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    if (!token) {
      this._router.navigate(["/main/login"]);
    }

    this.getTimelineItems();
  }

  getTimelineItems(): any {
    this.timelineItems$.subscribe({
      next: (items) => this.timelineItems = items
    })
  }
```

[See this solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k7agzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)